Replace round brackets and its content
I'm trying to replace some strings within round brackets. I'm able to replace the round brackets but not the text in it. The text is variable and not always the same, e.g. (9 seats free), (6 seats free) and so on. How can i solve it to replace both, brackets and its content?
$('myclass').children().each(function () {
  $(this).html(function (i, html) {
    return $(this).html().replace('mytext', '').replace(/\(|\)/g, "");
  });
});


use /\([^)]*\)/

you are using the myclass selector maybe you meant .myclass instead? plus you are only returning a string but you are not actually replacing text inside dom elements. The regex used is looking for a pipe inside parenthesis.. maybe you meant \(.+?\) instead? and one final thing, instead of using .html() you should use .text()

Why not keep the text upto the opening bracket and the text after the closing bracket? perhaps easier than trying to consider the length of text in between...

@RokoC.Buljan Thanks, that´s the solution!

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

@druplash "If an answer solved your problem, consider accepting the answer. Here's How does accepting an answer work?. Then return here and do the same with the tick/check-mark till it turns green. This informs the community, that a solution was found. Otherwise, others may think the question is still open and may want to post (more) answers. You'll earn points and others will be encouraged to help you. Welcome to Stack!"

a) myclass selector needs to be .myclass or #myclass
b) You need to change the regex to /\([^)]*\)/
c) also .html() should be .text() as you want to replace the text value
d) You can simplified your code as well.
$('.myclass').children().each(function () {
  $(this).text($(this).text().replace('mytext', '').replace(/\([^)]*\)/g, ""));
});

Working snippet:


$('.myclass').children().each(function () {
  $(this).text($(this).text().replace('mytext', '').replace(/\([^)]*\)/g, ""));
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="myclass">
  <p>mytext tries to shown a hardcoded (hardcoded) working example of the given working code (hope you can easily understand it). I hope you can easily understand it.</p>
  <br>
  <p>mytext second hardcoded (hardcoded) working example of the given working code. I hope you can easily understand it.[it will remove text only inside small brackets, not inside[] or {}]. {You get my point.}</p>
</div>



